# Return a list containing occurrence of each word of a list in another list

Tags: python

I would like to write a function that returns a list of integers, the integers are the occurrence of each word of a list(called my_words) in another list(called list_words). Let's say my function is called "mywords_occurrence" and the expected output is below:

```
my_words="apple pear lemon orange"
list_words="apple apple orange lemon banana orange kiwi tomato kiwi apple mango"
mywords_occurrence(my_words,list_words)
[3,0,1,2]
```

The function should return [3,0,1,2] because "apple" occurs 3 times in the list_words, "pear" occurs 0 time in the list_word etc.

My codes for the function is below:

```
def mywords_occurrence(my_words,list_words):
    my_words=my_words.split()
    list_words=list_words.split
    count=0
    l=[]
    i=0
    for n in range(len(list_words)):
        if my_words[i]==list_words[n]:
            count=count+1
            i=i+1
            l.append[count]
        else:
            i=i+1
            l.append[count]
    return l
```

When I tried my codes the error message pops up

```
for n in range(len(list_words)):
TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()
```

I tried to change `for n in range(len(list_words))` to `for n in list_words` but then another error message pops up

```
for n in list_words:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: FYI *"list containing occurrence of each word of a list in another list"* is called a ***counter***

Comment: Let me give you an alternative approach. First `import collections`. Then `counter = collections.Counter(list_words.split())`. Last line: `return [counter.get(word, 0) for word in my_words.split()]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
list_words = list_words.split
                            ^^^
```

Here you missed the () after `split`. Therefore it is actually the `split` method instead of the `split` result you want to obtain.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mywords_occurrence(my_words, list_words):
    my_words = my_words.split()
    list_words = list_words.split()
    word_dict = {word: 0 for word in my_words}
    for word in list_words:
        if word in my_words:
            word_dict[word] = word_dict.get(word) + 1
    return word_dict.values()
```

It's easier and faster with dictionaries.